# Short interval alarms in Android

Tags: android

I know that we can't set repeating alarms of short intervals in Android because it drains battery and has other such effects. Well, technically you can, but android will automatically push it up to a minute citing "suspiciously short duration".

So how exactly does an app like WhatsApp or Facebook constantly update our messages or newsfeed? I thought they fire an Alarm each second, but clearly that is impossible because the OS will push it up to a minute anyway. Using Handlers/Threads is off the question anyway because they don't fire when the app is closed, but WhatsApp updates your messages even when the app is closed.

So what exactly do these apps use if not AlarmManager to do the aforementioned task, and if they use AlarmManager, how do they set the short duration?

Comment: I think they run a service in background to catch notification from server.

Comment: So if you have a Handler running in a service, will it run even when the app is closed?

Comment: Yes I think. But why do you need a Handler ? If it's a push notification, you simply run your code whenever your receiver catch a notification, and update things to your desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a service that uses push messaging.  So basically they open a socket connection to a server and sleep until the server sends data to them.  Its an interrupt mechanism, not a poll.

Comment: A connection that doesn't terminate implicitly?

Comment: Sockets don't terminate implictly.  If you want them to close you need to do so explicitly.  They don't even timeout unless you write them to do so.

Comment: Then what happen when user change wifi or IP address ? Because normally they still receive update without open app right ? I think they used push notification, if that was the case, no socket connection needed.

Comment: A push notification *is* a socket. That's how it's implemented. How did you think it worked without one?

Comment: Really ? I didn't know this. But then how do it work when people change their IP address ? Because all I know is that to establish a socket connection, you need address of both sides right ?

Comment: It detects that the network connection was lost, and reconnected when a connection is reestablished. There's some logic surrounding it to work out cases like that, but at the heart it's just a socket.

Comment: Ok so the framework we used would handle it on it own. Interesting. I will keep digging in abit. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to any service like WhatsApp or Facebook, the idea behind this whole system works like this.

For Android in particular (or in general),

- Your device registers with the [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) service
- It allows GCM to create a [HTTP persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) with your device

  - This connection is lightweight and persistent (stay alive for a long time)

With this, you will be able to consume these services, sending messages in this fashion.

**Your Server ---> Google GCM Service ---> Target Device**

When you send your messages, do not include the whole message itself. You should keep it lightweight by just sending simple messages to notify the targeted device that it has new information to be downloaded.

At your device application, you set up permissions and intent to listen for these push notifications. Whenever, there is new messages, you will make a request to your server to receive the corresponding messages.

Here's a guide to explain in depth:  https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Cloud-Messaging

Cheers! Happy Programming!